# react native picker giving error when datasource is from json array

Tags: react-native, picker

i saw many post about how to use json data to load into react native picker
but whenever i access my json from async storage and access vehicles array to add it as datasource for picker then the app force closes with error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getString(ReadableNativeMap.java:168)

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      obj: null,
      name : '',
      email : '',
      phone : '',
      carbrand : '',
      carmodel : '',
      appointmentDate : '',
      appointmentTime : '',
      pickup : false,
      workshopNote : '',
      loaded: false,

    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    this._loadServices().done();

  }

  _loadServices = async () => {

    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserObj');
    this.setState({obj: JSON.parse(value)})

    //this.setState({userTypes: this.state.obj.vehicles})
    this.setState({ loaded: true })

    alert(this.state.obj.vehicles.brand)




render() {

if (this.state.loaded){
const selectedItem = this.state.obj.vehicles;

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>

            ....

          <Picker                      
             selectedValue={this.state.Year}
             onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ Year: itemValue })} >

        {this.state.obj.vehicles.map((item, value) => {

        return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={value} key={value} />)
        })}

        </Picker>


          ...


        </View> 
  )
}

return this.loading()


}
```

can someone please help me out with this?

p.s - json array is as follows

```
"vehicles": [
                {
                    "brand": "ASTON MARTIN",
                    "model": "RAPIDE",
                    "registration": "Mh 05 AP 866",
                    "year": "2018"
                }
            ],
```

Comment: Is it really that much effort to format your code?